# Dynamically generating headings with clickable list items displaying grouped contents

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Apologies for the vague title but this is a bit hard to explain... though I'll try my best!

I have a task to replicate some specific functionality on an application screen and thus while the method by which this is being done may seem odd, there is no allowance to variate from the specific task.

Firstly, all data is retrieved from an SQLite database. This retrieval part is no problem. The available columns in the database are:

```
pk (primary key)
heading_id
heading_name
sub_heading_name (can be duplicated on multiple rows with different contents)
sub_heading_contents
```

The final screen should display the following:

```
<heading_name>
    <clickable List(View?) of abbreviated sub_heading_contents>
<next heading_name>
    <next clickable list>
<etc...>
```

So basically just a list of headings and brief descriptions of sub_heading information. For instance, this might look like:

```
Food
    Sticky Date Pudding is a...
    Chocolate Cake tastes...
    Ice Cream can be...
    Pizza is often...
    Pasta once was...
    Burgers are...
```

Now, the weird thing is that while you see the list of sub heading details, when you click on any of them you are taken to a screen that shows information from every sub heading of the same name. In other words, clicking on the first 3 sub heading descriptions under food (pudding/cake/ice cream) would take you to another page under the sub heading name "Dessert" with all 3 descriptions listed on the same page, while clicking on the last 3 (pizza/pasta/burgers) would take you to a different page with the sub heading name "Mains". So you see all the sub heading descriptions in a big list in a seemingly unordered fashion but they are grouped by hidden sub heading names that are only apparent once you click on them to be taken to the next page.

So my problem now is... what would be the best way to store and reference the data retrieved from the database in order to create such a list? I've tried some variations of maps, treemaps, custom classes, lists, etc., but all seem to fall down at some point during the process (no doubt because I'm not using them properly!).

I wish I had some code to paste but it's all so disorganized at the moment I wouldn't even know where to start. Any even vague suggestions as to how such a thing might be accomplished would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a three-tier structure, of which only two tiers are directly user-visible. An example of this tiered structure, from your prose, is:

Food -> Dessert -> Pudding

For the purposes of this answer, I will call these the `topLevel`, `midLevel`, and `detail` tiers. I haven't the foggiest notion how this maps to your terms, as your prose suggests that both "Dessert" and "Pudding" are "sub headings", which muddies the waters. If "Pudding" appears in the UI, and "Dessert" does not, they are distinct things and should be treated as such in the data model.

Hence, this would appear to be three database tables, one for each tier, with classic 1:N foreign key relationships (i.e., the `midLevel` table has a column containing the key of the `topLevel` that contains it). Or, hold the entire tree representation in a separate file, in JSON or XML format, rather than a database.

From an in-memory data representation, a `TopLevel` holds a collection of `MidLevel` objects, each of which has a collection of `Detail` objects (again, using my terms, not yours).

In terms of UI, since you have elected to only show two tiers, you could use `ExpandableListView`, with `TopLevel` instances driving the parent nodes and the aggregate collection of `Detail` objects (for all `MidLevel` objects in the `TopLevel`) driving the child nodes.

The problem with your desired UI is that you have to have *all* of your `TopLevel`, `MidLevel`, and `Detail` objects in memory, at least to the level of knowing their parent-child relationships and enough data to drive the `ExpandableListView` UI. If your data model is big, this will be expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much. `ExpandableListView` seems like it could serve the purpose, though it will require a bit of work to implement in this case. I have found a few ideas from both that and related topics, however, which should be enough to go on from now and I can always put in time to get Expandable working if nothing else does. Also understood re. the memory expense. The model is not too big and unfortunately unchangeable so it should hopefully be OK. Thank you once again for your time and effort in both reading and responding to my mess of text, :).